# Fails to output all rows of data for participant

Tags: python, sorting

I am currently working on this data sorting thing, where I'm supposed to *(beside a bunch of other criterias)* only include rows of data for participants with at least 3 rows.

It seems like the method I'm using (line 9-16 and 37-40) fails to exclude the first line of data for participant(s) with at least 3 rows of data.
There is def a logic error here, can anyone seem to work out where my thinking went wrong? Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

##### The code

```
import csv

def preprocessing(raw_filename, output_filename):
    data=open(raw_filename)
    new=open(output_filename, "a")
    health_write=csv.writer(new)
    reader=csv.DictReader(data)
    health_write.writerow(reader.fieldnames) 
    counting_part={}
    for row in reader:
        checker = False
        participant_id=row['participant_ID']
        if participant_id in counting_part: 
            counting_part[participant_id]+=1
        else: 
            counting_part[participant_id]=1
        x=row['timestamp'].split()[0]
        if x.split('/')[-1] in ('2023'):
            if float(row['accuracy']) <= 30:
                if len(participant_id.split('-'))==5:
                    match=[]
                    for each in participant_id.split('-'):
                        match.append(len(each))
                        if match == [8, 4, 4, 4, 12]:
                            for elm in each:
                                if elm.islower() or elm.isdigit():
                                    value_lat=float(row['double_latitude'])
                                    value_long=float(row['double_longitude'])
                                    if (value_lat >= -180 and value_lat
                                        <= 180 and value_long >= -180
                                        and value_long <=180):
                                        if 0<=float(row
                                                    ['double_altitude'])<=1000:
                                            if row['provider'] in ['gps',
                                                                   'network']:
                                                checker = True
                                                
        if checker and counting_part[participant_id] >= 3: 
            for participant_key, count in counting_part.items():
                if participant_id == participant_key:
                    health_write.writerow(row.values())

    data.close()
    new.close()

    
preprocessing("example_raw.csv", "my_output.csv")
```

##### Some of the data:

```
row_id,timestamp,participant_ID,double_latitude,double_longitude,double_altitude,provider,accuracy
1,24/1/2023 1:05,2c9a7613-84f7-4c6d-af82,-37.80014035,144.963727,171.117,gps,41
2,24/1/2023 3:38,2c9a7613-84f7-4c6d-af82-9f54c8be2c1a,-37.80389128,144.9634838,143.159,gps,12.7445
3,24/1/2022 3:44,2c9a7613-84f7-4c6d-af82-9f54c8be2c1a,-37.80438867,144.9645387,19.95410156,gps,57.0303
4,24/1/2023 4:02,2c9a7613-84f7-4c6d-af82-9f54c8be2c1a,-37.80366035,144.9679344,56.83,gps,6.76879
5,24/1/2023 4:05,2c9a7613-84f7-4c6d-af82-9f54c8be2c1a,-37.80139125,144.9683195,55.13,gps,4.98383
6,15/7/2022 4:08,a7f3e14c-5db5-47e7-86c9-81f60e727d61,-37.80512032,144.9676758,4.723449707,gps,6.10221
7,15/7/2023 7:30,a7f3e14c-5db5-47e7-86c9-81f60e727d61,-37.80480437,144.9675091,95.83,gps,15
```

Comment: It would help to know what your "thinking" is.

Comment: There are no line numbers, so it's hard to tell what you mean when you say lines 9-16 and 37-40.

Comment: You only set `checker = True` if all the nested `if` conditions are true.

Comment: If the participant has at least 3 rows, you don't notice that until you get to their third row. So the first 2 rows will not be written.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing to the output file in the same loop where you're reading the rows and counting the rows by participant, you won't write anything for a participant until you get to their third row.

Instead of just using a counter, make a list of each participant's rows. Then at the end of the loop you can go through all the participants, writing all their rows if the row count is at least 3.

The per-participant dictionary can also contain the `checker` variable, which is set to `True` if all the conditions are true for any of the rows.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def preprocessing(raw_filename, output_filename):
    with open(raw_filename) as data
        reader=csv.DictReader(data)

        counting_part = defaultdict(lambda: {"checker": False, "rows": []})

        for row in reader:
            participant_id=row['participant_ID']
            counting_part[participant_id]['rows'].append(row.values())

            x=row['timestamp'].split()[0]
            if x.split('/')[-1] in ('2023'):
                if float(row['accuracy']) <= 30:
                    if len(participant_id.split('-'))==5:
                        match=[]
                        for each in participant_id.split('-'):
                            match.append(len(each))
                            if match == [8, 4, 4, 4, 12]:
                                for elm in each:
                                    if elm.islower() or elm.isdigit():
                                        value_lat=float(row['double_latitude'])
                                        value_long=float(row['double_longitude'])
                                        if (value_lat >= -180 and value_lat
                                            <= 180 and value_long >= -180
                                            and value_long <=180):
                                            if 0<=float(row
                                                        ['double_altitude'])<=1000:
                                                if row['provider'] in ['gps',
                                                                       'network']:
                                                    counting_part[participant_id]['checker'] = True



    with open(output_filename, "a") as new:
        health_write=csv.writer(new)
        health_write.writerow(reader.fieldnames)

        for item in counting_part.values():
            if item['checker'] and len(item['rows']) > 3:
                for row in item['rows']:
                    health_write.writerow(row)
```